# Error in R:Couldn't load all the content of a file when using read.table()

Tags: r, read.table

I want to use `read.table()` to read a file, but seems not all content could be loaded:

```
Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  invalid input found on input connection 'C:/Users/fhk/Desktop/data/data-20150808/20700_part'
```

Here is my code:

```
video_data <- read.table( 'C:/Users/fhk/Desktop/data/data-20150808/20700_part', fill = TRUE, col.names = c('id', 'video_code', 'video_content'),fileEncoding = 'utf8', colClasses = 'character');
```

There is 10000 records in my file 20700_part,but only 596 records can be loaded,and the last record has been cut off.

But if I reduce the scale of records to 595,it works.
Is there some way to fix it? Say, pass or set some parameter to load all the content?

Comment: What is the line #597?

Comment: So what is in record 595 that could break your loading? Separater issue? Qoutes etc etc.

Comment: Without seeing the content of the file it's hard to judge what's going wrong. These kinds of errors are very common in less than tidy data sets (which are usually entered manually).

Comment: line #596 is 1071019294194096 20700 游戏::单机游戏::❤我的世界Minecraft❤糖果的荒野求生第二集::0。line #597 is 1071019294194096 20700 游戏::单机游戏::【XY小源我的世界】萌萌村第二季第65期屌德斯与小熙被关在一起::0。The same format.@Pascal

Comment: If I copy the data you provided in the comment and use your code, I get it to work by providing `encoding="UTF-8"` instead of `fileEnc...`. I am not fully versed in the differences between the two, but it loaded the two lines without problem. (BTW: from `?file` in the "Encoding" section, it mentions that `"utf8"`is not portable, only `"UTF-8"` is. I don't think that's the problem you are seeing, just thought I'd mention it.) (BTW #2: using `encoding="UTF-8-BOM"` also worked, again not certain if it breaks things for you.)

Comment: Yeah,so I don't think the data's format caused this problem,maybe the scale of records is too large to be held.@r2evans